# How to import everything from <section id ="xxx"> into Google Sheets using importxml?

Tags: html, xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I want to import the list of companies of [this page](https://www.inc.com/inc5000eu/list/2018) into a Google Sheet and I only need the content of `<section id="data-container"> == $0`. I tried all sorts of combinations using

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.inc.com/inc5000eu/list/2018", "//section/[@id='data-container']") ,
=IMPORTXML("https://www.inc.com/inc5000eu/list/2018", "//section/*[@id='data-container']"), 
=IMPORTXML("https://www.inc.com/inc5000eu/list/2018", "//section/data-container") and others
```

but none of them seem to work, so I'm looking for a tip how to start things off correctly. This is my first time using HTML or XML. Most of the Youtube tutorials I've watched about thias topic copy tables and list from Wikipedia, which is way easier and clearer than this table. If I should provide more info about the HTML Code, please let me know. Thank you

Comment: Don't know if this is still relevant, but when using `IMPORTXML`, always start by viewing the source of the page, not the current content.